# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have looked all over but I can't really find  a clear example of this...

If $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ prove that it is a field... I understand that from the table we can see that the set is commutative, associative, and it has an identity. I'm not sure how to show the inverse $-a$ is in $F$, but by the table we can see that for take $2$  is in $F$ then if the inverse exists $-2$ is in $F$, and $2 + (-2) = 0$ but in the table we can see that $2 + 3 = 0$ so then $-2 = 3$? But I am just confused how that is possible, I know maybe it has something to do with mod but not sure how to tie it all together
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIWVq.png)

Comment: Can you add elements of this set without looking at the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a set "equivalence classes": we consider two integers $a$ and $b$ (such as $-2$ and $3$) to be "equivalent modulo $5$" if, divided by $5$, they have the same remainder. So
$$-2=5\cdot (-1)+\underbrace{3}_{\text{remainder}}\quad\text{and}\quad 3=5\cdot 0+\underbrace{3}_{\text{remainder}}\implies -2\equiv 3 \pmod{5}.$$
In a similar way, looking at your table we read that $3\cdot 4$ yields $2$:
$$3\cdot 4=12=5\cdot 2+\underbrace{2}_{\text{remainder}}\equiv 2\pmod{5}.$$

Comment: Any further doubts?

Comment: ok so, to show the additive inverse exists we can show that 2+3 mod5 = 0, and the inverse of 2 is 3, and 4+1 mod 5 = 0, and the additive inverse of 4 is 1 and we by this the additive inverse exists,.. I was mostly confused because in the notes it said if a is in F then -a is in F and a + (-a) = 0, so I thought it had to be the same a, I didnt realise -a can be any number as long as a + (-a) = 0 makes sense and in this case its a + (-a) mod5 = 0

Comment: Yes, exactly! Here $a\in F$ is not just a number, is the set of all integers with the same remainder.